# Bash script to filter specifc entries from snmpd.conf

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, snmp

I am working on a script to filter community entries from `snmpd.conf`
Script is:

```
SERVER=$(hostname)
touch /tmp/snmp_audit_$SERVER
echo $SERVER >> /tmp/snmp_audit_$SERVER
SNMP=$(cat /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf |grep -i rocommunity | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
echo $SNMP >> /tmp/snmp_audit_$SERVER
```

Which gives me output in below format:

```
rocommunity XXXX 1nn.nn.nnn.40
rocommunity XXXX 1nn.nn.nnn.0/24
rocommunity XXXX 1nn.nn.nnn.30
```

However, I want to filter those servers only, which doesn't have any of the below entries in snmpd.conf:

```
rocommunity XXXX 127.10.30.40
rocommunity XXXX 192.10.30.0/24
rocommunity XXXX 192.20.100.30
```

And for all those which doesn't have these entries, later I would need to add these ranges.
Also, I need to run it on multiple server over ssh, from a jump server where I have list of server names in a file.
Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `grep`:

```
grep -vxFf exclude.txt /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

Put the below entries in `exclude.txt`, basically it is your exclusion list:

```
rocommunity XXXX 127.10.30.40
rocommunity XXXX 192.10.30.0/24
rocommunity XXXX 192.20.100.30
```

- `-f exclude.txt` reads the pattern to match from file `exclude.txt`
- `-F` does fixed string matching instead of Regex pattern matching
- `-x` matches whole lines
- `-v` inverses the operation i.e. only non-matching lines will be shown

Comment: This will give me entries except the: "rocommunity XXXX 127.10.30.40
rocommunity XXXX 192.10.30.0/24
rocommunity XXXX 192.20.100.30" However, I am looking for a way to search servers which doesn't have these entries updated in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file. I didn't mean to get the entries excluding few specific. I mean to get the servers name which doesn't have any of these entries mentioned in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file.